# AWS Cognito - Is it possible to set different verification messages for different purposes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I've set up my user pool which uses email to login and I've set up email verification which requires the user to get the 6-digit code from their email. I want to use a different message for resetting passwords. What I have in mind is sending a one time link for this that would redirect users to the application I'm working on.

It seems like I can only modify one verification message which would be the same for both. Is there somewhere in the console that I can go to have two different messages?

Comment: Instead of changing message from console you can add custom email sender Lambda trigger and send different text based on `event.triggerSource` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-email-sender.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've gone to `aws update auth`, and added the Post Confirmation Trigger, you can do this for your [Post Confirmation Sign Up Lambda:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-email-sender.html)

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
   if (event.triggerSource === confirmSignUp) {}
   else {}
}
```